# complex internal vertices

Tags: vertices

i have managed to build this shape but i cant find a nice way to remove internal vertices. the "bean" was made with polyverts in the form of spheres so this shape is made from complete spheres and all the geometry is still there . i want to try printing it so need to remove all of that . any nice ideas . could not use the shrink wrap well for it .

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### BoolTool add-on

I'm not sure on what you mean by saying polyverts, but I'm am assuming that is something similar to parenting+vertex duplication...

[image]

So starting from a similar situation, after make the duplicate real, we have a plenty of different objects.

Download and install the [BoolTool add-on](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/BoolTool) that will allow us to merge all the objects with boolean operation.

Select all the objects, make the base mesh the active object (the biggest one: it's important that this object has at least a piece of volume in common with every sphere object) and choose from BoolTool tool tab the Direct Union tool.

[image]

It will take a while (depending on the number of spheres,their resolution and your hardware...for me about 15 minutes), but the result is quite good, clean and, above all, watertight.

[image]

Below a view of the insight. Notice how there is only a shell. The internal faces do not exist anymore.

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow thanks man . i give it a try . it sounds perfect . i see you went to some  effort to answer my question . thanks again :)

Comment: i had herd the parent vertex duplication called polyverts before yeah . super hand technique for the things i build .

Comment: i am having problems with the bool tool . tempramental results on my mesh .

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/UMz13.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc8Th.png

any ideas ?

Comment: I think is better to start a chat discussion about this aspect, join me there! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26480/complex-internal-vertices

Answer (score 4):

In edit mode select all the outside vertices with the circle select tool (C), make sure that the limit selection to visible button is on. Then hide the selected vertices (H), select all the inside vertices and delete them. ALT + H --. to unhide the outside vertices

Comment: thanks but i think the bool tool is the way to go . i dont want to be selecting  all the verts etc . thanks again .